# How to implement AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hey,
So I'm newish to Android and I have a class that fails immediately after it starts, and I deduced that it is because it times out. I was looking around the android documentation and found AsyncTask. I think that it is the solution to my problem-run the computation intensive process in the background. I don't really understand how to implement it though. My return type should be void because it doesn't return anything, it just changes a bunch of Button's colors based on an integer received from a different class. How can I implement AsyncTask? or should I be using something else?
Thanks.

Comment: Post some code to explain your question in a more better way.

Comment: If you want to show Ui to the user and do some background task at the same time. May be socket connecion or parsing or any thing like that in that case you need AsyncTask. there is preExecute(), doBackground and postExecute() methods. you can execute the method using exec().

Comment: You can check a detailed tutorial I have written on the subject: http://www.lothringer.co.uk/2011/example-of-asynctask-and-user-notification-in-android/ It explains in great details how to use user notifications in particular!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AsyncTask is what you want.  The [official tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) is pretty helpful.  Look into the `onPostExecute()` method to figure out how to end any sort of progress bar you may have.

Answer (score 2):

To start with AsyncTask, this :
http://jyro.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-asynctask-template.html
can really help you !
...contains explanations, source tarball and apk.

If you're really noob with Thread, Handler approach, you can take a look a this to start :
http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html

Hope this helps !
Chris D.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Ui to the user and do some background task at the same time. May be socket connecion or parsing or any thing like that in that case you need AsyncTask. there is preExecute(), doBackground and postExecute() methods. you can execute the method using exec().

Thanks
Deepak